# Apache2 won't start after change the path of SSL certificate via Webmin

Tags: permissions, apache2, ssl

I am new to Ubuntu Server. After changing newly created ssl certificate path on a virtualhost, apache2 won't start.

```
$ apache2ctl configtest // showing below error! 

    AH00526: Syntax error on line 171 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
    Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may.
    Action 'configtest' failed.
    The Apache error log may have more information
```

Line 171 is below

```
    <Directory /var/www>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

I revoke the change made and try to restart apache2. showing same error and all the sites down. If I # all the 5 line, Apache2 will start. however, sites displaying no permission to access. I am running wordpress on this server.

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is that a genuine hyphen, "-", or have you copied and pasted a similar but different character, such as "–", e.g. from a website?

Comment: Read the error - "either all options must start with + or -," - if you want symlinks to be folowed you need a + there, or a - to deny it.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the hint. and it got resolved.